# Why does the scrollBy problem occur in the presence of the Intersection Observer?

Tags: javascript

The task is as follows:

1. Have an Intersection Observer on the page to switch active menu items.
2. Have scrollBy on the page for smooth scrolling by anchors.

I saw such a problem: scrollBy scrolls to the element incorrectly, slightly confusing the coordinates by pressing the same button a second time - the scroll correctly gets into position. When I delete the Intersection Observer code, such a bug disappears, scrollBy scrolls immediately as it should. P.S.Sorry about Google Translate. I hope my question will be clear.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll("[data-observer-section]");
      const navs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-observer-nav]");
      setActiveLink();
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', setActiveLink);
      

      navs.forEach(nav => {
        nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            const href = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);    
            const scrollTarget = document.querySelector("#" + href);    
            const elementPosition = scrollTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            const offsetPosition = elementPosition - topOffset;    
            console.log(elementPosition)
            window.scrollBy({
                top: offsetPosition,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            }); 
        });
      });

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {            
            if(entry.isIntersecting ) {                
                location.hash = entry.target.getAttribute("id");
            }
        });    
      }, {  threshold: 0.55, rootMargin: sensitivity + "px" });       

    sections.forEach( section => {
        observer.observe(section);
    });

    function setActiveLink(){ 
        let hash = location.hash;
        console.log(hash)
        navs.forEach(nav => {
            if (nav.getAttribute("href") === hash) {
                nav.classList.add("active");
                nav.scrollIntoView({ inline: "center"});
            } else {
                nav.classList.remove("active");
            }
        });
    }});
```

[JSDiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzhit86/xbm3jkwg/2/) (You need to make the preview window as wide as a smartphone.)

Comment: I need a similar result with dodopizza.ru (mobile menu)

Comment: I'm clarifying the problem place: this is the nav.scrollIntoView({ inline: "center"});, which forces the active menu item to stand in the center. Without this, everything is fine. But I also need this functionality.

Comment: There are two many... non-trivial things in this code: the weirdest one is using scrollBy (which expected deltas) with absolute position (result of getBoundingClientRect). However, the most suspicious is using IntersectionObserver to trigger navigation as long as section is visible - this doesn't work well when there's an intentional scroll on clicking on nav panel, for example. What's the rrequirements for that?

Comment: @raina77ow Is required: 1) Change the class of menu items when scrolling the page (depending on the section) 2) Smooth scrolling to the anchor when clicking on the menu item. 3) The active menu item should always remain visible (preferably in the center). I mean, with a large number of menu items, there will be a horizontal scroll bar on mobile devices. Therefore, it is necessary that the menu scrolls automatically when switching the active item. Example: dodopizza . ru

Comment: Consider not using location.hash as storage of active element and treating it only as input for your component (so that specific parts of that can be referred). I suspect there's a race between browser trying to scroll into a view an element by its ID when hash changes - and your own scrollBy mechanism.